# Textview act like a terminal

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Hello I am trying to get text to display like it does in terminal or cmd. And by that I mean a window of text that with each input makes a new line and then displays the bottom line of the `TextView`, and there would be a set amount of lines always on the screen.

It sounded easy to do, but now that I started I'm not sure how to do it.

I tried putting a `TextView` in a `ScrollView` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100" >

<ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:minLines="11"
        android:maxLines="11"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</ScrollView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:onClick="buttonclick"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and then

```
sss=et1.getText().toString();
tv1.append("\n"+sss);
```

to add new lines

This all works but I really have no idea how to make the `TextView` go to the bottom, right now it just cuts off when I hit the max number of lines.

I definitely don't expect anyone to write my program for me. I am here to learn

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call `fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)` on the `ScrollView` after appending the text.

Comment: Thanks so much! Had to rewrite my layout file but i got it working.